# Create validation list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a validation list from a one dimension array. The problem is that this code only creates one element in the validation list. One big string with the delimiter and I would like to display all the element separated by the comma.

[image]

```
Sub test4()
    Dim aLineProd() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    ReDim Preserve aLineProd(100)
    
    Do
        aLineProd(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(LIGNEPRODUCTION_SHEET_NAME).Range(INITIALCELL_ADRESS).Offset(i).Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(LIGNEPRODUCTION_SHEET_NAME).Range(INITIALCELL_ADRESS).Offset(i).Value = ""
    
    ReDim Preserve aLineProd(i - 1)
    
    Call CreateValidationListGeneric(LINENUMBERABLE_ADRESS, aLineProd(), CHECKPRODUCTCODESHEET_NAME)
End Sub

Sub CreateValidationListGeneric(CellAdress As String, _
aValidationList() As Variant, sWorksheetName As String)

    With Worksheets(sWorksheetName).Range(CellAdress).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(aValidationList, ",")
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I have indented the code for you. **1.** Give your post a meaningful title. **2.** Explain what are you trying to achieve in the post. Title is not meant for that. **3.** Also explain in the post what were you expecting and what did you get including error message if any...

Comment: Thank you, it's my first post, I'm a new developer.

Comment: No problem. :) Just update your post as I mentioned above.

Comment: wait. i will update it

Comment: It works for me. My code puts all elements in separate line. How are you populating the array?

Comment: Sub test4()
    Dim aLineProd() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ReDim Preserve aLineProd(100)
    Do
        aLineProd(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(LIGNEPRODUCTION_SHEET_NAME).Range(INITIALCELL_ADRESS).Offset(i).Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(LIGNEPRODUCTION_SHEET_NAME).Range(INITIALCELL_ADRESS).Offset(i).Value = ""
    
    ReDim Preserve aLineProd(i - 1)
    
    Call CreateValidationListGeneric(LINENUMBERABLE_ADRESS, aLineProd(), CHECKPRODUCTCODESHEET_NAME)
    
    
End Sub

Comment: It is difficult to read code in comments. Next time please update the question. I have done it for you this time. Can you update the post with the screenshot of what you are getting?

Comment: Yep sorry, as you know I'm not familiar, i will update

Comment: Ok your code works just fine for me. It see there is something in that array which is creating the issue.. Ok gimme 2 hours. I am heading to the gym. Will come back to this post after that i.e if someone else already hasnt helped you :)

Comment: Thank a lot ! I wait for your help, good gym session ;)

Comment: @CLR may be right. Your region looks like it is France? `Application.International(xlListSeparator)` which I think is `;` for your region may help as mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this code does not work and always displays a single string, but with the delimiter ";". In the same workbook I have lists of validations that work with the separator ",". Do you have any other idea  ?

Comment: Possible to see your workbook?

Comment: Yes, How can we deal for it ?

Comment: can you upload the file to free file sharing site  for ex www.wikisend.com or dropbox and share the link here?

Comment: Yes i will just need to clear the data, will be upload in a few minutes thank again

Comment: To share the files i need you e-mail adress on dropbox, are you able to give it to me ?

Comment: no actually you do not need my email but anyways, you can upload the file to www.wikisend.com

Comment: Wikisend don't work, an error occured.. Do you have another one ?

Comment: I think in dropbox you are not using "Copy link" but "Share file" and hence it is asking for email address :) would you like to try that again?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vv8lbc7hotxb4pl/AACPvcebaLwGyn1vcql9egnka?dl=0

Comment: Thank you. What is the value of `LIGNEPRODUCTION_SHEET_NAME` and `INITIALCELL_ADRESS`?

Comment: Doent matter. found it

Comment: Its constant that contain a Name of sheet and the other is an cell adress, in this case it's A1. I prefer to work with constant, so you can find it in my mod const sheets

Comment: I think you deleted the sheet "LigneProduction_Data"?

Comment: Yes, because this data are quiet confidential

Comment: But it is only a range (one dimension) that contain a table with my whole production data line

Comment: I wanted to see the `Range(INITIALCELL_ADRESS).Offset(i)` values. are they confidential too? Maybe not from the screenshot?

Comment: i update the post, is that what you need ?

Comment: Ok no problem, i will try and use that

Comment: Just tested it. It works just fine for me. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7uycqqvx4sid8z1/Untitled.png?dl=0 Will delete this file after 1 hour.

Comment: I will try thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Apparently I couldn't name a cell with the name assigned to its range, I had to call it with the exact address of the cell: A1,C5 or something like this. I have no idea why but now it's working with an exact cell address

Comment: BTW you do not need a 1D array to achieve what you want :) You can directly work with table range ;)

Comment: Yes i think i need to be more comfortable with listobject ;), thanks again